# RecycleView for DataTable from Ulr Req

Tags: python, android-recyclerview, kivy-language

i have a app that show json results from urlrequest, i need to rappresent this data with recycleview selectable. Someone could help Me?? Thanks

line of recycleWiew  show multiple same line and not data from request

this is mai main:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.screenmanager import MDScreenManager
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivymd.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRectangleFlatIconButton
import datetime
from kivy.core.window import Window
import urllib
from kivy.network.urlrequest import UrlRequest
import json
from kivy.metrics import dp
import weakref
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior
from kivy.uix.recycleview.layout import LayoutSelectionBehavior
from kivy.uix.recycleboxlayout import RecycleBoxLayout
from kivy.uix.recyclegridlayout import RecycleGridLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty, ListProperty, StringProperty, ObjectProperty


class DataBase:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename
        self.users = None
        self.file = None
        self.load()

    def load(self):
        self.file = open(self.filename, "r")
        self.users = {}
        self.file.seek(0)
        for line in self.file:
            username, created = line.strip().split(";", maxsplit=1)
            self.users[username] = (created)
        self.file.close()

    def get_user(self):
        self.file = open(self.filename, "r")
        username = None
        for line in self.file:
            username, created = line.strip().split(";", maxsplit=1)
            self.users[username] = (created)
        if username:
            if username in self.users:
                return username
        else:
            return -1

    def add_user(self, username):
        if username.strip() not in self.users:
            self.users[username.strip()] = (username.strip(), DataBase.get_date())
            self.save()
            return 1
        else:
            return -1

    def update_user(self, username):
        self.users = {}
        if username.strip() not in self.users:
            self.users[username.strip()] = (username.strip(), DataBase.get_date())
            self.save()
            self.users = {}
            return 1
        else:
            return -1

    def validate(self):
        if self.get_user() != -1:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def save(self):
        with open(self.filename, "w") as f:
            f.seek(0)
            for key in self.users:
                f.write(f"{self.users[key][0]};{self.users[key][1]};\n")
            f.truncate()
    @staticmethod
    def get_date():
        return str(datetime.datetime.now()).split(" ")[0]


class CreateAccountScreen(MDScreen):
    user_input = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        user = db.get_user()
        if user != -1:
            self.ids.pl_actual_user.text = f'Utente attuale: "{user}"'
            self.ids.save_user.text = 'Aggiorna'
        else:
            self.ids.pl_actual_user.text = "Utente non definito"
    def submit(self):
        if self.user_input.text != "":
            if db.get_user():
                db.update_user(self.user_input.text)
            else:
                db.add_user(self.user_input.text)
            kronos_app.screen_manager.current = "kronosscreen"

    def refresh_recycleview(self):
        # ----- Update the recycleview data in the .kv file: ---- #
        user = db.get_user()
        if user != -1:
            self.ids.pl_actual_user.text = f'Utente attuale: "{user}"'
            self.ids.save_user.text = 'Aggiorna'

        #  ---- refresh the recycleview: ---- #

class BtnDownloadContainer(MDRectangleFlatIconButton):
    def __init__(self, text, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.icon = "download"
        self.pos_hint = {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
        self.size_hint = (1, 1)
        self.text = text

    def on_press(self):
        kronos_app.root.transition.direction = "left"
        kronos_app.fetch_containerlist()


class BtnDownloadShippingList(MDRectangleFlatIconButton):
    def __init__(self, text, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.icon = "download"
        self.pos_hint = {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
        self.size_hint = (1, 1)
        self.text = text

    def on_press(self):
        app = App.get_running_app()
        app.root.transition.direction = "left"
        app.fetch_shippinglist()


class BtnScann(MDRectangleFlatIconButton):
    def __init__(self, text, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.icon = "barcode"
        self.pos_hint = {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
        self.size_hint = (1, 1)
        self.text = text


class BtnSetting(MDRectangleFlatIconButton):
    def __init__(self, text, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.icon = "cog"
        self.text = text
        self.pos_hint = {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
        self.size_hint = (1, 1)

    def on_press(self):
        app = App.get_running_app()
        app.root.transition.direction = "left"
        app.createuser()


class ErrorScreen(MDScreen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.ids.pl_error.text = f'Errore di connessione!\n\nVerifica la connessione e riprova.'

    def submit(self):
        kronos_app.screen_manager.current = "kronosscreen"


class ListScreen(MDScreen):
    pass


class KronosScreen(MDScreen):
    keyboard = ObjectProperty()
    key = ObjectProperty()
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(KronosScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.main_grid = GridLayout()
        self.main_grid.cols = 1
        self.btn1 = BtnDownloadContainer(text="Preleva lista Container")
        self.btn2 = BtnDownloadShippingList(text="Preleva Lista Spedizioni")
        self.btn3 = BtnScann(text="Avvia Scansione")
        self.btn4 = BtnSetting(text="Profilo")
        self.main_grid.add_widget(self.btn1)
        self.main_grid.add_widget(self.btn2)
        self.main_grid.add_widget(self.btn3)
        self.main_grid.add_widget(self.btn4)
        self.add_widget(self.main_grid)

class DialogContent(MDBoxLayout):
    pass


class SCManager(MDScreenManager):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

class SelectableRecycleBoxLayout(FocusBehavior, LayoutSelectionBehavior,
                                 RecycleBoxLayout):
    ''' Adds selection and focus behaviour to the view. '''


class SelectableLabel(RecycleDataViewBehavior, GridLayout):
    ''' Add selection support to the Label '''
    index = None
    selected = BooleanProperty(False)
    selectable = BooleanProperty(True)
    cols = 3

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        ''' Catch and handle the view changes '''
        self.index = index
        self.label1_text = str(index)
        self.label2_text = data['label2']['text']
        self.ids['id_label3'].text = data['label3']['text']  # As an alternate method of assignment
        return super(SelectableLabel, self).refresh_view_attrs(
            rv, index, data)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        ''' Add selection on touch down '''
        if super(SelectableLabel, self).on_touch_down(touch):
            return True
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and self.selectable:
            return self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index, touch)

    def apply_selection(self, rv, index, is_selected):
        ''' Respond to the selection of items in the view. '''
        self.selected = is_selected
        if is_selected:
            print("selection changed to {0}".format(rv.data[index]))
        else:
            print("selection removed for {0}".format(rv.data[index]))


class DataTableRV(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(DataTableRV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        paired_iter = zip(items_1, items_2)
        self.data = []
        for i1, i2 in paired_iter:
            d = {'label2': {'text': i1}, 'label3': {'text': i2}}
            self.data.append(d)

items_1 = {'apple', 'banana', 'pear', 'pineapple'}
items_2 = {'dog', 'cat', 'rat', 'bat'}
#globals
db = DataBase("kronos.txt")
sm = SCManager()
Builder.load_file('kronos.kv')

class KronosApp(MDApp):
    dialog = None
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.title = "Kronos v1.0"
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self):
        Window.size = (460, 460)
        self.screen_manager = sm
        screens = [KronosScreen(name="kronosscreen"), CreateAccountScreen(name="createuser"),
                   ListScreen(name='listscreen'), ErrorScreen(name="errorscreen"),]
        for screen in screens:
            self.screen_manager.add_widget(screen)
        self.screen_manager.current = "kronosscreen"
        return self.screen_manager

    def connection_error_show(self):
        kronos_app.root.transition.direction = "left"
        self.screen_manager.current = "errorscreen"

    def container_on_row_press(self, instance_table, instance_row):
        """
        Called when a table row is clicked. and get list of element of row table child
        """
        start_index, end_index = instance_row.table.recycle_data[instance_row.index]["range"]

        # loop over selected row items
        self.fetch_container_detaillist(instance_row)
        kronos_app.root.transition.direction = "left"
        kronos_app.screen_manager.current = "kronosscreen"

    def fetch_containerlist(self):
        """
        Get via http post a list of containers to manage for outbound/inbound shipment
        :param instance: Container list
        :return: List of outbound Container
        """
        scren = self.root_window

        def show_container_item(req, result):
            """
            [{'IdSpedizione': '30', 'IdProducer': 'FM', 'IdContainer': 'MEDU7753924', 'QuantitaTotale': 2350},
            {'IdSpedizione': '31', 'IdProducer': 'FM', 'IdContainer': 'HLXU8610510', 'QuantitaTotale': 2065}]
            """
            json_result = json.loads(result)
            list_row_data = []
            for x in range(0, len(json_result)):
                list_dr = []
                for key in json_result[x]:
                    # escludo il parametro mode nella vista
                    if key != 'Mode':
                        list_dr.append(json_result[x][key])
                data_row = tuple(list_dr)
                list_row_data.append(data_row)
            """self.data_table_container = MDDataTable(
                pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.43},
                size_hint=(1, 0.85),
                check=True,
                use_pagination=False,
                rows_num=100,
                column_data=[
                    ("Spedizione", dp(20)),
                    ("Produttore", dp(25)),
                    ("Container", dp(30)),
                    ("Q.ta", dp(25)),
                ],
                #row_data=list_row_data,
                row_data=[

                ]
            )"""
            self.screen_manager.current = "listscreen"
            #self.data_table_container.bind(on_row_press=self.container_on_row_press)
            #self.screen_manager.get_screen("listscreen").add_widget(self.data_table_container)
            data = list_row_data
            rv = SelectableRecycleBoxLayout()

            self.screen_manager.get_screen("listscreen").add_widget(rv)
            for line in data:
                print(line)
                #w = DataLine(id_spedizione=line['IdSpedizione'], id_producer=line['IdProducer'], id_container=line['IdContainer'], qta_tot=str(line['QuantitaTotale']))  # instancing the class

            #self.screen_manager.get_screen("listscreen").ids['data_table_container'] = weakref.ref(self.data_table_container)


        if db.validate():
            # get the loaded product list
            url_endpoint = "http://edi.kronos.biz/api/Logistics/GetContainers/?"
            # Checked: If Contaier is scanned or not (Container da controllare)
            # SaveJsonFile: solo per Gianluca
            headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json'}
            params = urllib.parse.urlencode({'Checked': 'false', 'SaveJsonFile': 'False'})
            req = UrlRequest(
                url=url_endpoint + params,
                #on_error=lambda *args: print('error:', args),
                #on_failure=lambda *args: print('fail:', args),
                on_failure=self.connection_error_show(),
                on_error=self.connection_error_show(),
                # on_redirect=lambda *args: print('redir:', args),
                on_success=show_container_item,
                method='Post',
                req_headers=headers,
                timeout=20,
            )
            #data = [{'IdSpedizione': '30', 'IdProducer': 'FM', 'IdContainer': 'MEDU7753924', 'QuantitaTotale': 2350},
            #        {'IdSpedizione': '31', 'IdProducer': 'FM', 'IdContainer': 'HLXU8610510', 'QuantitaTotale': 2065}]

            # convert into json
            #final = json.dumps(data, indent=2)
            #show_container_item(req=None, result=final)
        else:
            self.screen_manager.current = "createuser"

    def fetch_shippinglist(self):
        scren = self.root_window
        self.btn1 = BtnDownloadContainer(text="Preleva lista Container")
        self.screen_manager.ids.listscreen.add_widget(self.btn1)
        if db.validate():
            pass
        else:
            self.createuser()

    def createuser(self):
        self.screen_manager.current = 'createuser'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    kronos_app = KronosApp()
    kronos_app.run()
```

and this my kv file

```
#:import utils kivy.utils

<CreateAccountScreen>
    on_pre_enter: self.refresh_recycleview()
    id: sc_create_account
    name: "createuser"
    user_input: user_input

    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        spacing: "50dp"
        padding: "20dp"
        adaptive_height: True
        pos_hint: {"top": 1}
        MDLabel:
            id: pl_actual_user
            text: "Utente Attuale"
            font_size: 20
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
            halign: "center"

        MDTextField:
            id: user_input
            mode: "round"
            hint_text:'Nuovo Operatore'
            icon_right: "account"
            size_hint_x: None
            width: 300
            font_size: 20
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}

        MDGridLayout:
            cols: 2
            padding: 0, 10, 0, 0
            spacing: dp(25)
            size_hint: 1, None
            height: self.minimum_height

            MDAnchorLayout:
                size_hint_y: None

                MDRoundFlatIconButton:
                    text: "Salva"
                    id: save_user
                    size_hint_x: None
                    with: None
                    font_size: 20
                    line_color: "#dadada"
                    ## icon: "mdi-checkbox-marked-circle-outline"
                    theme_icon_color: "Custom"
                    on_press: root.submit()
                    on_release:
                        root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
                        root.current: 'kronosscreen'

            MDAnchorLayout:
                size_hint_y: None

                MDRoundFlatIconButton:
                    text: "Annulla"
                    size_hint_x: None
                    with: 100
                    font_size: 20
                    line_color: "#696969"
                    ## icon: "error"
                    ## icon_color: "green"
                    on_release:
                        root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
                        app.root.current = "kronosscreen"

<ErrorScreen>
    id: sc_error_screen
    name: "errorscreen"

    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        spacing: "50dp"
        padding: "20dp"
        adaptive_height: True
        pos_hint: {"top": .8}

        MDLabel:
            id: pl_error
            text: "Errore di connessione"
            font_size: 20
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
            halign: "center"

        MDRoundFlatIconButton:
            text: "Back"
            ##size_hint_x: None
            size_hint: 1, .4
            pos_hint: {'y': .3}
            with: 100
            font_size: 20
            line_color: "#696969"
            icon: 'reply'
            ## icon_color: "red"
            on_release:
                root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
                app.root.current = "kronosscreen"

<ListScreen>:
    id: listscreen
    name: "listscreen"
    rv: rv
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size_hint_y: 1
        Label:
            id: listscreen_title
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 40
            font_size: 15
            color: (0, .65, .91, .8)
            text: ''
        DataTableRV:
            id: rv
            viewclass: 'SelectableLabel'
            SelectableRecycleBoxLayout:
                default_size: None, dp(56)
                default_size_hint: 1, None
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
                orientation: 'vertical'
                multiselect: True
                touch_multiselect: True

<SelectableLabel>:
    # Draw a background to indicate selection
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (0, .65, .91, .8) if self.selected else (0, 0, 0, 1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    label1_text: 'label 1 text'
    label2_text: 'label 2 text'
    label3_text: 'label 3 text'
    pos: self.pos
    size: self.size
    Label:
        id: id_label1
        text: root.label1_text
    Label:
        id: id_label2
        text: root.label2_text
    Label:
        id: id_label3
        text: root.label3_text
```

the result is the image below but i need to show the result of my urlrequest on